# Linker optizimation

Tags: visual-c++, linker, dynamic-linking, static-linking

My linker (`link.exe` from Microsoft Visual C++ 2005) probably tries to optimize its job and does not statically link all the objects a `*.lib` file contains into final executable, which is necessary for me because of profiling tasks that follow. How can I force link.exe to include all the symbols (that even are not referenced in the source code) into final executable?

So the problem is that I have a library file, `mylib.lib`, which contains `foo.obj`, `bar.obj` and `qux.obj`.

My source code files reference symbols from `foo.obj`.

When I link statically source code with library file `mylib.lib`, it links only to `foo.obj`, no other symbols are joined to the final executable, whereas I need them there (so that they are loaded into memory along with process).

I tried many solutions, no success. Is it optimization? I don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

To a certain extent, that's how linkers work - they pick out those object modules that contain symbols that are referenced by the library or executable that it is supposed to build and ignore the rest. That's not really an optimisation, that's the way they are supposed to work.

The easiest way to ensure that the additional object files are linked into the executable is by referencing a symbol in them. Just make sure you have "function level linking" turned off as that will negate the effect of referencing the symbols.